# Count how many objects in an array has a certain value (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, like so:

```
[
{
"_id": "5b09cc3495cb6c0487f1166b",
"name": "ccc",
"email": "ccc@gmail.com",
"phone": "790467522",
"kidsNo": "1",
"adultsNo": "1",
"fullDate": "2018/5/1",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "1",
"chosenHour": "11:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5b09cc6095cb6c0487f1166c",
"name": "asd",
"email": "asd@asd.pl",
"phone": "790467522",
"kidsNo": "2",
"adultsNo": "3",
"fullDate": "2018/5/1",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "1",
"chosenHour": "12:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5b0b1560c7b4fd0c33b2d52e",
"name": "dddd",
"email": "dddd@ddd.pl",
"phone": "123123112",
"kidsNo": "2",
"adultsNo": "1",
"fullDate": "2018/5/17",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "17",
"chosenHour": "11:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

In the future this array will contain much more objects. 
I'm trying to solve this using map and for it seems to be quite complicated.
That's the challenge: 
how I can count how many objects have certain value? How can I get to know how many times someone booked something to day===1? The best result would be an array like this:

```
[{dayOne: 2}, {dayTwo: 5}, {dayThree:1}.......and so on],
```

where `value` is the value of how many times a day was booked(key), hence how many times certain object(with certain value) has appeared in the array?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Array.filter(item => item.day === 1)

Comment: I'm curious about your output format.  What is the advantage of that over `{day1: 2, day2: 5, day3: 1, /* ... */ }` or `{1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 1, /* ... */}` or even `[2, 5, 1, /* ... */ ]`?  Any of those looks easier to use and easier to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get result exactly in that format you can do this.

```js
const objs = [
{
"_id": "5b09cc3495cb6c0487f1166b",
"name": "ccc",
"email": "ccc@gmail.com",
"phone": "790467522",
"kidsNo": "1",
"adultsNo": "1",
"fullDate": "2018/5/1",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "1",
"chosenHour": "11:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5b09cc6095cb6c0487f1166c",
"name": "asd",
"email": "asd@asd.pl",
"phone": "790467522",
"kidsNo": "2",
"adultsNo": "3",
"fullDate": "2018/5/1",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "1",
"chosenHour": "12:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5b0b1560c7b4fd0c33b2d52e",
"name": "dddd",
"email": "dddd@ddd.pl",
"phone": "123123112",
"kidsNo": "2",
"adultsNo": "1",
"fullDate": "2018/5/17",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "17",
"chosenHour": "11:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
}
]

const days = [['dayOne', 1], ['dayTwo', 2], ['dayThree', 3]];

const res = days.reduce((acc, v) => {
  const obj = {};
  obj[v[0]] = objs.filter(x => x.day == v[1]).length;
  return acc.concat(obj);
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Note that you will need to extend the `days` array for every day you want to include like that. So If you want to include all 31 possible days, you need this.

```js
const objs = [
{
"_id": "5b09cc3495cb6c0487f1166b",
"name": "ccc",
"email": "ccc@gmail.com",
"phone": "790467522",
"kidsNo": "1",
"adultsNo": "1",
"fullDate": "2018/5/1",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "1",
"chosenHour": "11:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5b09cc6095cb6c0487f1166c",
"name": "asd",
"email": "asd@asd.pl",
"phone": "790467522",
"kidsNo": "2",
"adultsNo": "3",
"fullDate": "2018/5/1",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "1",
"chosenHour": "12:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5b0b1560c7b4fd0c33b2d52e",
"name": "dddd",
"email": "dddd@ddd.pl",
"phone": "123123112",
"kidsNo": "2",
"adultsNo": "1",
"fullDate": "2018/5/17",
"year": "2018",
"month": "5",
"day": "17",
"chosenHour": "11:00",
"chosenRoom": "x",
"__v": 0
}
]

const days = [['dayOne', 1], ['dayTwo', 2], ['dayThree', 3], ['dayFour', 4], ['dayFive', 5],
              ['daySix', 6], ['daySeven', 7], ['dayEight', 8], ['dayNine', 9], ['dayTen', 10],
              ['dayEleven', 11], ['dayTwelve', 12], ['dayThirten', 13], ['dayFourteen', 14],
              ['dayFifteen', 15], ['daySixteen', 16], ['daySeventeen', 17], ['dayEighteen', 18],
              ['dayNineteen', 19], ['dayTwenty', 20], ['dayTwentyone', 21], ['dayTwentytwo', 22],
              ['dayTwentythree', 23], ['dayTwentyfour', 24], ['dayTwentyfive', 25], ['dayTwentysix', 26],
              ['dayTwentyseven', 27], ['dayTwentyeight', 28], ['dayTwentynine', 29], ['dayThirty', 30],
              ['dayThirtyone', 31]];

const res = days.reduce((acc, v) => {
  const obj = {};
  obj[v[0]] = objs.filter(x => x.day == v[1]).length;
  return acc.concat(obj);
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Which in this example returns `[{dayOne: 2}, {dayTwo: 0}, ..., {daySeventeen}: 1, {dayNineteen: 0}, ...]`

Answer (score 6):

To count objects by a condition, you can use `.filter` --

```
let firstDayCount = arr.filter(x => x.day === "1").length;
```

To group the result by days, you can use `.reduce` --

```
let countByDays = 
  arr.reduce((res, { day }) => {
     res[day] = res[day] || 0;
     res[day] += 1;
     return res; 
   }, {});
```

If you want to format your output, you can then use a dictionary of names --

```
let dayNames = { 1: "dayOne", 2: "dayTwo" /* and so on */}

let formattedResult = 
  Object.keys(countByDays)
    .map(n => { [dayNames[n]]: countByDays[n] });
```

---

Note that using a `.filter` for counting creates an intermediate throw-away array. We're not storing a reference anywhere, so it has to be GCed soon, but if it really affects your performance *measurably* in a real-life scenario, you can use a `.reduce` instead -- something that is called ["deforestation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation_(computer_science)):)

```
let count = arr.reduce((cnt, el) => el.day === "1" ? cnt += 1 : cnt, 0);
```

It'll still create an intermediate anonymous object though -- a reducer function -- so if your profiler shows this place as a bottleneck, you might be best off using a `for` loop. As always in such cases, it's up to you to find the right spot between performance and readability in your own real-world scenarios.

Comment: function `filter` for counting is the worst approach!

Comment: Worst compared to what?

Comment: To the fact of creating a new array.

Comment: We're not storing a reference anywhere, so I assume it's going ot be GCed soon. Though if it really affects the performance significantly in a real-life scenario, one can always go with a `for` loop :)

Comment: For counting the best is a for-loop as you said or a reduce.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to group and count.

```js
const array = [{"_id": "5b09cc3495cb6c0487f1166b","name": "ccc","email": "ccc@gmail.com","phone": "790467522","kidsNo": "1","adultsNo": "1","fullDate": "2018/5/1","year": "2018","month": "5","day": "1","chosenHour": "11:00","chosenRoom": "x","__v": 0},{"_id": "5b09cc6095cb6c0487f1166c","name": "asd","email": "asd@asd.pl","phone": "790467522","kidsNo": "2","adultsNo": "3","fullDate": "2018/5/1","year": "2018","month": "5","day": "1","chosenHour": "12:00","chosenRoom": "x","__v": 0},{"_id": "5b0b1560c7b4fd0c33b2d52e","name": "dddd","email": "dddd@ddd.pl","phone": "123123112","kidsNo": "2","adultsNo": "1","fullDate": "2018/5/17","year": "2018","month": "5","day": "17","chosenHour": "11:00","chosenRoom": "x","__v": 0}],
      result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {day}) => {
        let key = `day${day}`;
        (a[key] || (a[key] = {[key]: 0}))[key]++;
        return a;
      }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note though that `Object.values` won't work in IE without a polyfill.

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda only in old versions.

Comment: Hmm, that's really unexpected :) I've tried it in IE11 just now and it worked, though I always avoided it because MDN said otherwise --https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility